# React nested loop unique key issue

Tags: reactjs, loops, dictionary, dom

I am just looking answer in general without glimpse to code. I have a couple levels deep object in JSON file when looping once and returning items there is no problem with a key, but when I loop twice then there is the key error. I tried many strange things like after looping once return div with unique key and loop again inside that div and other online suggested things but didn't work. Should I treat somehow differently nested loops in react or maybe there is some rule?

Comment: It seems you have a problem with your code. However, we can't help unless we have [code or information that can reproduce the problem](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Otherwise, we are just blindly guessing.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure what your specific issue is without seeing some code, but what you might be experiencing is a duplicate key issue from a nested loop (this would happen if you set the key based only on the inner or outer loop incrementing value).

One way to create a unique key in that case would be to set the key as the combination of the outer and inner incrementing values. Note that your loop is probably 0-indexed, so multiplying won't work. Here's a generic code example to explain - it is pushing some JSX elements into an array to be rendered by a React component, and uses both `i` and `j` variables to set the key:

```
addElements() {
  const elements = []
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
      elements.push(<div key={`${i}${j}`}></div>)
    })
  }
  return elements
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>{this.addElements()}</div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone can try to use the

```
<React.Fragment key={item.id}>
</React.Fragment>
```

Docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html